# jQuery click() and append() not responding on iterated divs

Tags: jquery, click, append

I'm iterating this div and the script with it, so that a user can add an answer to the three default options (question-editor-answer-container). But clicking on "add answer" doesn't work and I can't see why.

I had this working for a single one, but the trouble started when I had to make adjustments for having many divs on the same page. Other containers (popup.question-editor) have a different ids, like 13,14,15, etc. Those are placed via PHP, which is probably not relevant.

```js
var container = $(".popup.question-editor#12");
container.find(".add-answer").click(function() {
  var order = null;
  order = container.find('.question-editor-answers div:last-child .correct').attr('value');
  order = parseInt(order) + 1;
  container.find('.question-editor-answers').append($('<div class="question-editor-answer-container"><span class="question-answer"><input type=text name="answers[]" /></span><span class="question-correct"><input type="radio" class="correct" value="' + order + '"name="correct"  /></span></div>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup question-editor" id="12">
  <span class="close" id="close">X</span>
  <form method="post" lpformnum="4">
    <p>
      <label>Question</label>
      <textarea name="question" class="question-input"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Answers</label>
    </p>
    <div class="question-editor-answers">
      <div class="question-editor-answer-container">
        <span class="question-answer">
      <input type="text" name="answers[]">
     </span>
        <span class="question-correct">
      <input type="radio" class="correct" name="correct" value="0">
     </span>
      </div>
      <div class="question-editor-answer-container">
        <span class="question-answer">
      <input type="text" name="answers[]">
     </span>
        <span class="question-correct">
      <input type="radio" class="correct" name="correct" value="1">
     </span>
      </div>
      <div class="question-editor-answer-container" id="found">
        <span class="question-answer">
      <input type="text" name="answers[]">
     </span>
        <span class="question-correct">
      <input type="radio" class="correct" name="correct" value="2">
     </span>
      </div>
      <div>Something</div>
    </div>
    <div class="add-answer" id="add-answer"><span>add</span></div>
    <p></p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="reuse" value="1">Allow reuse (what does this mean?)
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="add_question" value="add">
      <input type="hidden" name="category" value="1">
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ids starting with numeric character:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

[W3C Recommandation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

Comment: Thanks. But jQuery does selected it, so that's not the issue.